# What are overhang conductors?

Tags: synchronous, alternator, self-induction

I am asking this in the context of synchronous generators.

From the textbook "*The Performance and Design of Alternating Current Machines*", page 421, under the heading "**3.Synchronous Reactance**" of the CHAPTER XVII **SYNCHRONOUS MACHINES: THEORY**

> Leakage reactance results from real self flux linking the armature slot and overhang conductors, producing a corresponding volt drop \$Ix\$...

I understand it mathematically, via Faraday's law of self induction:

$$
e = -L\frac{dI}{dt} =-L \frac{d}{dt} \big(I_0 e^{-j\omega t} \big) = jI\omega L = jIx
$$

I can't visualize what is happening really actually. I would be grateful if somebody could explain what overhang conductors (with proper diagram) are and how it acts as self inductance.